# Not able to access scope variable from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying retrieve list of files on a remote server and display them on a web page. 
The scope variable `fileListOnCTP` holds the list of files , which is accessed from webpage. But the webpage does not display  the list of files. However ng-inspector shows the variable holding the correct value. Can someone tell me where I might be going wrong ?

```js
$scope.listOfFilesOnCTP = "";
 $scope.fileListOnCTP = "";
 $scope.GetListOfFilesonCTP = function(path){ 
 $scope.listOfFilesOnCTP = RdaService.getListOfFilesonCTP(encodeURIComponent(path)).then(function(response){
   var newData = response.data;
   console.log(newData);
   return newData;
   });
 console.log($scope.listOfFilesOnCTP);  // --> Displaying the file list correctly
  //path = path.replace(/\//g, '_');
 $scope.fileListOnCTP = $scope.listOfFilesOnCTP;  
 };
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-3" id="CTP Jobs">
  <h3>JOBS</h3>
  <table class="table table-striped">
   <div ng-model="fileListOnCTP" ng-init="GetListOfFilesonCTP('/home/topas/rda_app/JOBS')">
    <span><tr>{{fileListOnCTP}}  <!-- Variable not getting resolved although it shows correct value in controller -->
     </tr></span>
   </div>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can't just simple do a `ngModel` on a DIV, only on inputs/textarea (Unless you use a directive that require `ngModel`)

Comment: If the return value is an Array, you probably want an ng-repeat. What is the type of fileListOnCTP?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. But I haven't had luck without using ng-model as well..

Comment: @BobS it is a string

Comment: Based on the code you provided `$scope.listOfFilesOnCTP` and `$scope.fileListOnCTP` are both promises so they are not gonna have the value you are looking for, have you tried setting `$scope.fileListOnCTP` in your `.then`? (ex: `$scope.fileListOnCTP = newData` or something of that sort)

Comment: Try to instantiate your `$scope.fileListOnCTP` into the `RdaService.getListOfFilesonCTP()` function

Comment: @CShark Yes. Assigning fileListOnCTP to newData worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `RdaService.getListOfFilesonCTP` returns a promise, you need to update the `$scope` variables inside of the `then`, because this is where you can get the resolved value of the promise. If you try to set your `$scope` variable elsewhere, there is no guarantee the service would have returned a value yet, which is why your previous code didn't work.

For reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api